# Sails.js Mocha Timeout Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, mocha.js

Thanks ahead of time for any help.

I have a Sails.Js (v11) app and I'm using Mocha for unit testing.  Currently, I'm getting a timeout error everytime I try and run a test:

```
Error: timeout of 30000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

I've set a timeout of 20000 on my test bootstrap file and 30s on mocha.

Bootstrap file:

```
var Sails = require('sails');

 // Global before hook
  before(function (done) {
    this.timeout(20000);
    // Lift Sails with test database
    Sails.lift({
      log: {
        /**
         * for debugging:
         * level: 'error'
         */
         level: 'error'
        /**
         * for running full tests without sails console errors
         * level: 'silent'
         */
        //level: 'silent'
      },
      hooks: {
        grunt: false
      },
      models: {
        connection: 'test',
        migration: 'drop'
      }
    }, function(err, server) {
      sails = server;
      if (err)
        return done(err);
        done(err, sails);
    });
  });

  // Global after hook
  after(function (done) {
    console.log(); // Skip a line before displaying Sails lowering logs
    Sails.lower(done);
  });
```

Mocha:

```
--timeout 30s
```

Any idea how to fix this error?

Comment: Does It still hang if you remove your global after hook?

Comment: @PeterHauge Hi Peter.  Yes, it still fails.

Comment: If you have a timeout of 20,000 on your `before` and it's timing out after *30* seconds, then it seems like the problem is in the test itself, not the `before` (also, I think it would mention it specifically if the `before` was timing out).  You can change the log level to `verbose` and make sure Sails is lifting, or thrown a log before `done(err, sails)` to make sure it gets there.  Can you post the actual test you're running?

Answer (score 2):

Try removing all the done() function calls from your `global after hook`. You do not need the done() call if the function isn't an `asynchronous hook`.

```
   // Global after hook
  after(function () {
    console.log(); // Skip a line before displaying Sails lowering logs
    Sails.lower();
  });
```

*Edit*

I think I see your problem. You need to do `sails.lower();` NOT `Sails.lower();` (Note the capitials)

Here is another example:

```
before(function (done) {
    var SailsApp = require('sails').Sails;
    var Sails = new SailsApp();
    Sails.lift({
    }, function (err, sails) {
        done(err, sails);
    });
});
describe.skip("dummy test", function () {
        it('is a pending dummy test case', function () {
        });
    });

after(function (done) { 
    sails.lower();
    done();
});
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion of removing the after hook and removing the done call.  I'm still getting a timeout error

Answer (score 0):

open the mocha.opts and set 
--timeout 600s

and then open bootstrap.test.js
and set  this.timeout(60000);

```
var sails = require('sails');

before(function(done) {

// Increase the Mocha timeout so that Sails has enough time to lift.
this.timeout(60000);

sails.lift({
// configuration for testing purposes
}, function(err, server) {
 if (err) return done(err);
 // here you can load fixtures, etc.
 done(err, sails);
   });
});

after(function(done) {
// here you can clear fixtures, etc.
 sails.lower(done);
});
```

It takes time for sails app to lift so we need to give a large timeout for test to start.
If timeout is small then test cases start running even the the app is not live and it gives error.

Answer (score 0):

I've found unit testing starting up the full sails framework for each unit test is generally too slow.  How I've been working around it to stub sails by assigning the part of it I need to a variable, then using rewire to substitute it during test runtime.

```
var sails = ifDef("sails");
var stormpath = require("stormpath");

// I check if 'sails' is defined', if so use it, if not, just leave it null
// so I can rewire it during test run time.
var config = ifDef("sails.config");

module.exports = {

  init: function () {

    var settings = {
      config.apiKey,
      config.apiSecret
    };
  },    
};

function ifDef(test) {
  try {
    return eval(test);
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Then in the unit test, I'm using [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) to substitute undefined vars that's provided by sailsjs during the test.

```
var rewire = require("rewire");

var fakeconfig = {
  apiKey: "wabawaba",
  apiSecret: "jojojo"
};
var stormpath = require('stormpath');

var FooService = rewire("../api/services/FooService");
FooService.__set__("config", fakeconfig);
```